# UITextField Changes Not Being Detected?

Tags: variables, swift, int, uitextfield, boolean

I have two flag properties that should change when a text field contains an integer, and I have IBActions, when the text field editing ends, that change the flags. When both of the variables are true, those methods should enable a button. I ran the iOS simulator, but the button isn't enabling. I also declared the text field delegate for both the text fields.

I am new to swift, so please be clear with your answer. Also, I haven't set any breakpoints. Here's the code for what I have so far:

```
var yourWeightFilled = false
var calorieNumberFilled = false

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
    let text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if textField == yourWeightTextField {
        yourWeightFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    } else if textField == calorieNumberTextField {
        calorieNumberFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    }

    return true
}

@IBAction func yourWeightEditingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
    yourWeightTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func calorieNumberEditingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
    calorieNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITextField` is a subclass of `UIControl` and thus needs to have [action methods registered](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:) to be called in response to control events. You do that with the `addTarget(_:action:forControlEvents:)` method.

For example:

```
weightField.addTarget(self, action:"yourWeightEditingDidEnd:", forControlEvents:.EditingDidEnd);
```

Would work in your case to call your action method `yourWeightEditingDidEnd()` when the user finishes editing the text field. This assumes your field property is named `weightField`. A good place for this code is in your view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method.

There is one more important step. You appear to be implementing UITextFieldDelegate, which is good because you also need a `textFieldShouldReturn(textField:) -> Bool` method that returns true and [resigns the text field as first responder](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder). Example:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder();
    return true;
}
```

This in turn causes the .EditingDidEnd control event to fire and the action method you registered to be called.

Comment: Thanks! One question, I'm new to this, so where would be an appropriate place to add these 2 lines of code in the code I have written so far! Thanks!

Comment: I outlined that in the answer. You should most likely do it inside of viewDidLoad().

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I'll let you know if I have issues.

Comment: Just one more question: how would I do this if I wanted to do it when the value did change (What would I change the control event to instead of .EditingDidEnd)?

Comment: See the documentation for Control Events for that. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events

Comment: Oh no problem. I will

Comment: Click the check mark below the up/down vote buttons.

Comment: Also, you need to go back and accept the answers on other questions you've asked. If you don't accept the answers then we don't get points for helping you and you'll get less help.